# Span and Dimension: A subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-writing

If $A$ is finite set of linearly independent vectors then the dimension of the subspace spanned by $A$  is equal to the number of vectors in $A$.

This is obviously true. Since $A$ is a finite set of linearly independent vectors and spans a subspace, $A$ is a basis for that subspace spanned by $A$ and thus by definition the dimension of a vector space is equal to the cardinality of any basis.

I would help with writing the above argument in a concise, precise manner with mathematical notation and other shorthand

Secondly in general what tips and/or advice you could give in general to make my arguments and proofs as efficient (time-wise) as possible.

Comment: Than you really want to see this written in symbols or what?

Comment: by the way that prove is not easy!

Comment: hmm you have to define efficiently! Cause I'm a bit confused you could always define a symbol that will contain a whole argument.  
Because as I remember it you need the Lemma of Zorn for that prove!

Comment: Okay understanding your question correctly now you're trying to find out how in mathematics one definition, argument, lemma or law might be put as simple as possible. Both readable and short. The answer to this in my opinion is a bit annoying but. If you figure out how to put a problem as simple as possible, readable and short. That is almost the same as the solution! Or how my professor did put it once:
*Why did we put this definition. Because then the solution is trivial!*

Comment: puh this question if like really hard!

Comment: Because this is basically what mathematics is all about!

Comment: did you ever found a good example to express arguments because that would greatly help us!

Comment: @mjb4: Getting to find the "as simple as possible, but no simpler" solution is the *hardest* part of getting a solution. Sorry about that.

Comment: I don't know if this is of help, but perhaps some tecnological measure could help you overcome your disability. For example, learn LaTeX to write math on the computer.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are after. I'd say the bounty is wasted.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter How can make it clearer?

Comment: @mjb4 Zorn's Lemma is required to prove that every vector space $V$ has a basis, where the proof uses the fact that a basis can be characterized as a maximal linearly independent subset of $V$. Here $A$ is assumed to be linearly independent already, so there's no need to prove that the space spanned by $A$ has a basis; the basis is provided for us already.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Can you perhaps help?

Comment: @Matthew your proof in words should be perfectly good for any respectable linear algebra course. Maybe you should add an explicit remark about why $A$ is both linearly independent and spanning in the space spanned by $A$ (which, you know... isn't exactly difficult).

Comment: @DustanLevenstein So, it can't be shorted with mathematical symbols?

Comment: @Matthew Maybe a bit (e.g. now that I think about it, it would also be good to give a name to the vector subspace spanned by $A$, to ease your sentence structure a bit). But it seems to me as though you're falling prey to the myth in mathematics that pure symbolic notation is preferable to English.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Like this $U= span(A)$

Comment: yes, like that. Or even the sentence "Let $U$ be the space spanned by $A$." ;-)

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Could I than say since $A is a set linearly independent vectors and spans U is it a basis for U. Is that not too circular?

Comment: I mean, it's nearly tautological, because it follows directly from the assumptions. Not circular, though.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein How would write the argument without the tautological statement

Comment: I didn't say you should avoid the tautological statement. A basic linear algebra course is likely to expect that for this problem.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein No other suggestions?

Comment: not particularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips that I follow when writing proofs.

- Write in complete sentences including punctuation.  (This seems contradictory since there are often so many symbols in math proofs.  But symbols have exact meanings in words.  For example, $\exists$ means "there exists".  Anywhere you see $\exists$, in your mind you can replace that symbol with "there exists".  In this way, math proofs should be paragraphs of complete sentences with punctuation.)
- Write down the relevant definitions first.  Often, the proof is just showing that the circumstances match the definitions.

I think you're trying to prove the statement: if $A$ is a finite set of linearly independent vectors then the dimension of the subspace spanned by $A$ is equal to the number of vectors in $A$.

Here is one proof:  The dimension of a vector subspace is the size of any of its bases.  (Recall the theorem: all bases of a vector subspace have the same size.)  A basis for a vector subspace $V$ is a set of linearly independent vectors that spans the subspace.  We are given that $A$ is a set of linearly independent vectors.  Therefore $\text{Span}(A)$ is a subspace, and its dimension is $|A|$ (the number of elements in $A$).